# Understanding connection between RFID reader and PC

Tags: rfid

I am new to RFID transmission and would love some help!  In setting up an RFID system, the questions I have are:

```
1.) Can an RFID reader transmit data to a remote online server/cloud?    
    (e.g. an tag is read in Texas and transmitted to Vermont)
2.) Can multiple servers be hooked up to an individual reader 
    (e.g. if tag meets criteria 1, query server 1, if tag meets  
    criteria 2, query server 2)
3.) If yes to 1 or 2, does this require a specific type of reader?
```

Any supporting materials would be much appreciated -- this resource has been particularly useful so far [Link](http://ijergs.org/files/documents/RFID-58.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1. In general yes.  Some advanced (and expensive) readers have Linux onboard and allow you to run apps inside reader. So technically you can achieve it.

Usually readers are not that smart, so they only track tags and store their info inside reader's memory to be read by any external client (com, usb or ethernet)

2. Most readers don't allow multiple client connections. So you primary scenario is to place one server close to reader and make it poll reader for nearby tags. Once server receive tag data from reader it then share it with other servers.
3. Yes.